# How to convert java code to jstl

Tags: jstl

I cannot found the way to convert java code to jstl

This is my java code

```
for(int i=0;i<listCategory.size();i+=3){
    int size = i+3<listCategory.size() ? i+3 : listCategory.size
     for(int j=i;j<size;j++){
        Category cate = lisCategory.get(j);
     }
}
```

Please help me :(

Answer (score 1):

Hi I’m not sure if I understand what you want, but ill try to help you if I can, The JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library (JSTL) is a collection of useful JSP tags which encapsulates core functionality common to many JSP applications.  Below is the tag for the core libary.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" 
       uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

If you want to emulate your for loop from Java you would use the <`c:forEach>` Tag.  This will allow you to iterate over a list in your JSP page assuming you include the taglib provided above.  Here is an example for you to view.

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<title><c:forEach> Tag Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5">
   Item <c:out value="${i}"/><p>
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this gives you some insight or helps you along your journey.